# Getting a particular array and echo its value

Tags: php

I have this script from a free website file. Here is the subject script:

```
foreach ($auth as $a => $a1) {
    //$a = strtoupper($a);
    if (in_array($a, array('CASH','VOTE','ID','IP','PLAYTIME','PCOIN','CREATEDATE','LAST','SPENT','CONNECTSTAT','VIP','VIP_FREE','EXPIRED','CTL1_CODE'))) {
      if ($a == 'CTL1_CODE') {
          $a = 'STATUS';
          $a1 = user_status($a1,'ctl');
      }
      $results[] = array('name'=>preg_replace('/_/i',' ',$a),'data'=>$a1);
    }
}
```

How to get the value of `ID` and echo it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you clean up the code, it’s easy to see how to access the `ID` value:

```
foreach ($auth as $a => $a1) {
    //$a = strtoupper($a);
    if (in_array($a, array('CASH','VOTE','ID','IP','PLAYTIME','PCOIN','CREATEDATE','LAST','SPENT','CONNECTSTAT','VIP','VIP_FREE','EXPIRED','CTL1_CODE'))) {
      if ($a == 'CTL1_CODE') {
          $a = 'STATUS';
          $a1 = user_status($a1,'ctl');
      }
      if ($a == 'ID') {
          echo $a1;
      }
      $results[] = array('name'=>preg_replace('/_/i',' ',$a),'data'=>$a1);
    }
}
```

Just adding the check for `ID` will work:

```
if ($a == 'ID') {
    echo $a1;
}
```

**EDIT** And if you want to access it outside of the `foreach` loop, just do this. I have an `if` conditional to just check if the value exists.

```
if (array_key_exists('ID', $auth) && !empty(trim($auth['ID'])) {
    echo $auth['ID'];
}
```

Or, since your `foreach` loop is creating `$results` you can access that value this way instead:

```
if (array_key_exists('ID', $results) && !empty(trim($results['ID'])) {
    echo $results['ID'];
}
```

Comment: hello,thank you for your respons, but what if i  dont want to put inside on the foreach, i mean i will use the value od 'ID' for a another page